# List of RadioListTile not selected on UI flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm build a question-quiz app. when I fetch data successfully and display list of RadioListTile for every question include answer (A, B). but when I selected into Radio. It does not reflect changes to the Ui means it does not select the pressed radio button.
My code is here :

```
class CauHoiModel{
  int id;
  String dapAn;//A, B, C, D
  QuestionModel({this.id, this.dapAn});
}
class QuestionListState extends State<QuestionList>{
  List<CauHoiModel> _list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for(var i = 0; i < widget.questions.length; i++){
      _list.add(CauHoiModel(id: widget.questions[i].id, dapAn: ""));
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Column(
            children:[
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.questions.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text("Câu ${index+1} " + widget.questions[index].title,
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                            ),
                            RadioListTile(
                              title: Text(widget.questions[index].ABCD.answerA.value),
                              value: CauHoiModel(id: widget.questions[index].id, dapAn: "A"),
                              groupValue: _list[index],
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _list[index] = value;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                            RadioListTile(
                              title: Text(widget.questions[index].ABCD.answerB.value),
                              value: CauHoiModel(id: widget.questions[index].id, dapAn: "B"),
                              groupValue: _list[index],
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _list[index] = value;
                                });
                              },
                            ),                            
                          ],
                        )
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "$soPhut",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.red),
              )
            ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs `selected` property to be set.

Simply, define a map (or do your best) for storing answers, then set selected property of `RadioListTile`

```
var answers = Map();

RadioListTile(
  ...
  selected : answers[index] == "A",
  onChanged : (value) {
    setState(() {
        ...
        answers[index] = "A";
    });
  },
),

RadioListTile(
  ...
  selected : answers[index] == "B",
  onChanged : (value) {
    setState(() {
        ...
        answers[index] = "B";
    });
  },
),
```